# padding not working

Tags: css

I want to add some space above the heading. I have added:

```css
padding-top: 200px !important;
```

[image: The problem!]

Appriciate your help to solve this issue.

Also I wonder how can I add spaces (padding top/bottom) to h1,2,3,4,5 & 6 tags so when ever I apply heading to a text, the padding should be applied automatically instead of adding additional class or style. I don't want to use line-height?

Note: I'm using Elementor Pro + Hello Theme.

Thanks

Comment: The issue here isn't that the padding isn't there (it is, the green shows that) it's that the element above it has some other positioning, probably a `float` that means the padding goes in front of the element above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<span>` tags is a inline element and inline elements don't react well with padding.

You can target the **h1** - **h6** as you said, but if you want to target the `<span>` you will need to add `display: inline-block;` as well for it to work with padding.

Also, this has nothing to do with WordPress as this is a pure CSS question, for future questions that don't involve WP use stackoverflow.